# How to access a referencing outlet from a different view controller?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am new to Swift and Xcode. I am building an Financial Expense ios app.

In my first view controller, I created a referencing outlet for a label called expenseNum.

In my second view controller, I have a function for a button called Add Expense. When it is clicked, I need it to update the expenseNum variable with the amount of the expense.

What is the best way to go about this? I had created an object of the first view controller class and accessed it like "firstviewcontroller.expenseNum"  but this will create a new instance of the class and I need it to be all the same instance so it can continuously add to the same variable. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a delegate

```
 protocol SendManager {
    func send(str:String)
 }
```

**In first**

```
class FirstVc:UIViewcontroller , SendManager {

      func send(str:string) {
        self.expenseNum.text = str
     }

}
```

when you present SecondVc

```
let sec = SecondVc()

sec.delegate = self
```

// present

**In second**

```
class SecondVc:UIViewcontroller {

   var delegate:SendManager?

   @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {

      delegate?.send(str:"value")

  }
}
```

// setting delegate

in `viewDidLoad` of SecondVc

```
if let first = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as? FirstVc {
   self.delegate = first
}
```

Comment: Where do you place protocol SendManager {
    func send(str:String)
 }

Comment: Do you define the protocol in the first view controller or the second?

Comment: anywhere it will be accessible above the class declaration

Comment: Okay so I defined the protocol at the top of the file with the first view controller in it. Is that correct? When you say "when you present secondVc" where do you place that code?

Comment: yes , it's correct ---- how do you show secondVC present / segue / push ?

Comment: Not exactly sure... I'm working with a tabbed application. The first tab is the first view controller and the second tab is the second view controller.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, with the edit the "let sec = SecondVc()

sec.delegate = self" is still there. Does this need to be placed anywhere or does the if statement do this?

Comment: this was for segue, present / push ,,,, but in your case the if statement replaces it

Comment: a little improvement over answer 
1 make the protocol class specific like this
protocol SendManager: class {
    func send(str:String)
 }

2. declare a weak delegate to save it from retaining a memory cycle

weak var delegate:SendManager?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can pass data from `ViewController2` to another `ViewController1`

The best way here is **Protocol Delegates**

**Please follow below steps to pass data**

In Your `SecondViewController` from where you want to send data back declare a protocol at the top of class declaration

```
protocol SendDataBack: class {
    func sendDataFromSecondVCtoFirstVC(myValue: String)
}
```

Now in the `class` , declare a object of your protocol in same `ViewController`

`weak var myDelegateObj: SendDataBack?`

And now in your  **Add Expense** button action just call the delegate method

```
myDelegateObj?.sendDataFromSecondVCtoFirstVC(myValue: yourValue)
```

**Now go to your first `ViewController`**

the place from where you have pushed/present to SecondViewController you must have taken the object of SecondVC to push to push from first

```
if let secondVC = (UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVCID") as? SecondViewController {
        vc?.myDelegateObj = self

 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true) 
**OR**
        self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

> now in your FirstViewController make an extension of FirstViewVC

```
extension FirstViewController: SendDataBack {
    func sendDataFromSecondVCtoFirstVC(myValue: String) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: your should make a weak delegate to save It from retain a memory cycle and from memory leaks!! like this weak var myDelegateObj: SendDataBack?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a variable in your properties in second ViewController (before viewDidLoad method)

```
var delegate: FirstViewController? = nil
```

and use from the properties of the first view controller anywhere of the second view controller.

```
delegate!.mainTableView.alpha=1.0
//for example access to a tableView in first view controller
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use a public var. Add a new Swift file to your project, call it Globals. Declare the public variable in Globals.swift like so:
`public var theValue: Int = 0`
Set its required value in the first ViewController, and you'll find you can read it in the second with ease.